# How to double the array elements value

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have array elements and I am trying to  multiply by 2 only using **filter** method (not map).The output I am expecting something looks like this [2,4,6,8,10].Here is my code

```
  var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
  array.filter( val => val * 2);
```

Comment: yes ,the easy way is to use map but I am interested in trying with filter.

Comment: No. You shouldn't use filter. That is not how filter works. It is just for filtering.

Comment: I suppose you need to read the notion of filter method.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: why must you only use the `filter` method?

Comment: You're asking us how to cook with a freezer.

Answer (score 4):

Not [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) , you should use `map` function in this case.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
array = array.map(function(val){return val*2;});
console.log(array);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/op1h5w8w/)

Answer (score 1):

By using only the filter method... you could try using it as like an iterator (note that this is NOT how filter is supposed to be used):

```
 var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
 array.filter( function (val, i, array) { array[i] = val * 2; });
 //array now has [2,4,6,8,10]
```

This is ugly, but this is what you would do if you can only use `filter`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
 var new_array = array.map(function(e) { 
      e = e*2; 
      return e;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand the functions of `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`.

From your requirement it should be function of `map` but you want with `filter` which is not obvious.

**Map:**

```
When you call map on an array, it executes that callback on every 
element within it, returning a new array with all of the values 
that the callback returned.
```

**Filter**

```
filter executes that callback on each element of the array, and spits
out a new array containing only the elements for which the callback returned true.
```

```js
let items = ['1','2','3','4','5'];

let numbers = items.map(item=>item*2);

console.log(items);
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use filter() you could to that:

```
Array.prototype.filter = Array.prototype.map
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
array.filter( val => val * 2);
```

But please don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8 ];

var doubleUp = (array) => array.map(item=>item*2);

console.log(doubleUp(numList));
```

//returns
[
2,  4,  6,  8,
10, 12, 14, 16
]